# JQuery resize is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues with resizing in my code where rest of methods are all working fine. I tried editing the `draggable` and `resizable` methods but nothing worked.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLvuhwan/).

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    VerileriTekrarOlustur('<div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="divKolon ui-resizable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="margin-left: 0px; position: relative; width: 245px; right: auto; height: 127px; bottom: auto; left: -5px; top: 28px;"><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><div class="divIcKolonGrup ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative;"><div style="float:left;">Adress</div><div class="divIcKolon ui-resizable" style="height: 10000px;"><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div></div></div><div class="divIcKolonGrup ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative; width: 225px; right: auto; height: 0px; bottom: auto; left: -76px; top: 53px;"><div style="float:left;">Numara</div><div class="divIcKolon ui-resizable" style="width: 119px; height: 10000px;"><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div></div></div></div>');                
});

function VerileriTekrarOlustur(Data)
{       
    var GeciciDiv=document.getElementById("Kolonlar");
     $(GeciciDiv).append(Data);
    var GeciciDivChildren=GeciciDiv.children;
    console.log(GeciciDivChildren);

    for(var i =0;i<GeciciDivChildren.length;i++)
    {
        var divGeciciKolonChildren=GeciciDivChildren[i].children;

        for(var x=3;x<divGeciciKolonChildren.length;x++)
        {
            var divGeciciKolonChildrenChildren=divGeciciKolonChildren[x].children;
            //var KolonChildrenChildren=document.createElement("div");
            //$(KolonChildrenChildren).draggable();
            $(divGeciciKolonChildren[x]).draggable();
            $(divGeciciKolonChildrenChildren[1]).resizable();
            for(var j=0;j<divGeciciKolonChildrenChildren.length;j++)
            {
                //KolonChildrenChildren.appendChild(divGeciciKolonChildrenChildren[j]);

            }
            //console.log(KolonChildrenChildren);
        }
        $(GeciciDivChildren[i]).draggable();
        $(GeciciDivChildren[i]).resizable();
    }                                       
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="Kolonlar" style="margin-top :10px"> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divKolon {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:3px solid #00000; background-color: #E98A7E;float:left;}

.divUstKolon {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:3px solid #DD4B39;  text-align:center;float:left;margin-right:20px;}
.divIcKolon{width:50px;height : 20px !important;padding:10px;border:3px solid #00000;background-color: #FFFFFF ; text-align:center;float:left;margin-left:5px;}
.shadow(@shadow){
  -webkit-box-shadow:@shadow;
  -mox-box-shadow:@shadow;
  box-shadow:@shadow;
}

.divIcKolonGrup{border 3px solid #00000;}    

.label-danger{      
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;        
}
```

Comment: May i know why aren't you using html textarea which usually has resizing ability by default?

Comment: what it the diffrent i get some issue from textarea